# How do I vertically align and stack both my tabs and grid divs to stack neatly on top of each other?

Tags: html, css

As it stands, I see that my tab div is roughly 2px bigger than my grid div (to the right) -circled in red. How do I go about changing either the HTML markup or CSS to neatly stack both my tabs and grid divs on top of each other so that they line up.

I have attached a PIC of the problem as well as the expected result:

[image]

[image]

Here's the CSS and HTML in question:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>MRSP Accomodations Manager</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/jqx.classic.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jqxcore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jqxmenu.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jqxgrid.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jqxgrid.selection.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jqxgrid.columnsresize.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jqxdata.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        
            var source =  {
                datatype: "json",
                datafields: [
                    { name: 'LastName' },
                    { name: 'FirstName' },
                    { name: 'Floor', type: 'int' },
                    { name: 'Office' }
                ],
                id: 'id',
                url: 'compile_data.asp'
            };
        
        var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
        
        
        $("#grid").jqxGrid({
        width: '100%',
                height: '100%',
                source: dataAdapter,
                columnsresize: true,
                columns: [
                    { text: '<b>LastName</b>', datafield: 'LastName', width: 250 },
                    { text: '<b>FirstName</b>', datafield: 'FirstName', width: 150 },
                    { text: '<b>Floor</b>', datafield: 'Floor', width: 180 },
                    { text: '<b>Office</b>', datafield: 'Office', width: 120 }
                ]
            });
        });
        
        
    </script>
    <style>
        * {
        font-family: Segoe UI;
        font-size: 10.5pt;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        }
        .jqx-grid {
        border-radius: 0 !important;
        }
        body {
        height:100%;
        }
        header {
        background-color: rgb(93,90,88);
        color: white;
        border: 0;
        margin:0;
        line-height: 25px;
        padding-left: 2px;
        }
        footer {
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
        margin:0;
        border:0;
        line-height:25px;
        background-color: rgb(93,90,88);
        width:100%;
        color: #FFF;
        padding-left: 2px;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
        box-sizing: border-box; 
        }
        #wrapper {
        position:absolute;
        width:100%;
        margin:0;
        }
        #topbar {
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-left: 2px;
        background-color: rgb(216,216,216);
        color: rgb(76,83,92);
        }
        .center {
        margin: auto;
        border: 3px solid #73AD21;
        padding: 10px;
        }
        .input_txt_search {
        background: url(icons/search.png) no-repeat right;
        background-size: 16px;
        border: 1px solid rgb(171,173,179);
        padding: 2px;
        width: 200px;
        background-color: #FFF;
        }
        .input_txt {
        border: 1px solid rgb(171,173,179);
        padding: 2px;
        width: 200px;
        }
        .input_txt:hover, .input_txt_search:hover, .selectbox:hover  {
        border-color: rgb(93,90,88);
        }
        .selectbox {
        width: 206px;
        padding: 2px;
        border: 1px solid rgb(171,173,179);
        background: url(icons/arrow.png) no-repeat right #fff;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        background-position-x: 182px;
        }
        input:-webkit-autofill,
        input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
        input:-webkit-autofill:focus, 
        input:-webkit-autofill:active  {
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
        color: white !important;
        }
    </style>
    <style>
        p {
        margin: 0 0 20px;
        line-height: 1.5;
        }
        .main {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
        }
        .content {
        background: #fff;
        border: 1px solid rgb(171,173,179);
        }
        .content>div {
        display: none;
        padding: 20px 25px 5px;
        }
        input[name="tabs"] {
        display: none;
        }
        label {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
        border-top: 1px solid rgb(171,173,179);
        border-left: 1px solid rgb(171,173,179);
        border-right: 1px solid rgb(171,173,179);
        width: 115px;
        padding: 10px;
        }
        label:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        background: rgb(196,196,196);
        }
        input[name="tabs"]:checked+label {
        background: #fff;
        color: #000;
        border-top: 1px solid rgb(171,173,179);
        border-left: 1px solid rgb(171,173,179);
        border-right: 1px solid rgb(171,173,179);
        border-bottom: 0px;
        position: relative;
        font-weight: bold;
        }
        input[name="tabs"]:checked+label::before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 1px;
        background: #fff;
        bottom: -1px;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin: auto;
        }
        #tab1:checked~.content #content1,
        #tab2:checked~.content #content2,
        #tab3:checked~.content #content3,
        #tab4:checked~.content #content4 {
        display: block;
        }
    </style>
    <%
        sub add_new
        
            Dim strSQL
        
            strSQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_offices " & _
                    "(LastName, FirstName, Floor, Office) " & _
                    " VALUES (" & _
                    "'" & Request.Form("LastName") & "', " & _
                    "'" & Request.Form("FirstName") & "', " & _
                    "'" & Request.Form("Floor") & "', " & _
                    "'" & Request.Form("Office") & "' " & _
                    ")"
        
            Response.Write(strSQL)
        
        end sub
        
        
        
        
        %>
</head>
<body>
    <header>MRSP Accomodations Manager</header>
    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="topbar">
            <form name="GO" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="Search" class="input_txt_search" />
                <input type = "submit" name="GO" value="GO"/>
                <input type = "submit" name="Test" value="Test" onclick="test()"/>
            </form>
            <%
                if Request.Form("GO") = "GO" then           
                
                    search
                
                End If
            %>
        </div><!-- End of DIV Wrapper -->

        <div class="center">

            <div id="content">
                <div class="main">
                    <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked><label for="tab1">Office Info</label>
                    <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs"><label for="tab2">Employee Info</label>
                    <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs"><label for="tab3">Service Requests</label>
                    <input id="tab4" type="radio" name="tabs"><label for="tab4">Tokyo</label>
                    <div class="content">
                        <div id="content1">
                            <form method="post">
                                <table style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 5px;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>FirstName:</td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="FirstName" class="input_txt"  /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>LastName:</td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="LastName" class="input_txt" /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Floor:</td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="Floor" class="input_txt"/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Office:</td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="Office" class="input_txt"/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Options:</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <select class="selectbox">
                                                <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                                                <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type = "submit" name="Submit" value = "Submit"/></td>
                                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </form>
                            <%
                                If Request.Form("Submit") <> "" then                 
                                
                                add_new
                                
                                End If
                                %>
                        </div>
                        <div id="content2">
                            <p>
                                London is the capital city of England and the United Kingdom. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants. Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia,
                                its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                London's ancient core, the City of London, largely retains its 1.12-square-mile (2.9 km2) mediaeval boundaries and in 2011 had a resident population of 7,375, making it the smallest city in England. Since at least the 19th century, the term London has
                                also referred to the metropolis developed around this core.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="content3">
                            <p>
                                Mumbai is the capital city of the Indian state of Maharashtra. It is the most populous city in India, most populous metropolitan area in India, and the eighth most populous city in the world, with an estimated city population of 18.4 million and metropolitan
                                area population of 20.7 million as of 2011. Along with the urban areas, including the cities of Navi Mumbai, Thane, Bhiwandi, Kalyan, it is one of the most populous urban regions in the world.
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                Mumbai lies on the west coast of India and has a deep natural harbour. In 2009, Mumbai was named an alpha world city. It is also the wealthiest city in India, and has the highest GDP of any city in South, West or Central Asia.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="content4">
                            <p>
                                Tokyo, officially Tokyo Metropolis, is one of the 47 prefectures of Japan. Tokyo is the capital of Japan, the center of the Greater Tokyo Area, and the most populous metropolitan area in the world. It is the seat of the Japanese government and the Imperial
                                Palace, and the home of the Japanese Imperial Family.
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                Tokyo is in the Kantō region on the southeastern side of the main island Honshu and includes the Izu Islands and Ogasawara Islands. Tokyo Metropolis was formed in 1943 from the merger of the former Tokyo Prefecture and the city of Tokyo.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="grid"></div>

        </div><!-- END OF DIV #CONTENT-->

    </div><!-- END OF DIV #CENTER -->

    </div><!-- END OF DIV #WRAPPER -->

    <footer>User: KELLYJ</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try apply following CSS to your grid div :

```
#grid {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

You can see the result in code snippet.

Hope it helps !

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        
            var source =  {
                datatype: "json",
                datafields: [
                    { name: 'LastName' },
                    { name: 'FirstName' },
                    { name: 'Floor', type: 'int' },
                    { name: 'Office' }
                ],
                id: 'id',
                url: 'compile_data.asp'
            };
        
        var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
        
        
        $("#grid").jqxGrid({
        width: '100%',
                height: '100%',
                source: dataAdapter,
                columnsresize: true,
                columns: [
                    { text: '<b>LastName</b>', datafield: 'LastName', width: 250 },
                    { text: '<b>FirstName</b>', datafield: 'FirstName', width: 150 },
                    { text: '<b>Floor</b>', datafield: 'Floor', width: 180 },
                    { text: '<b>Office</b>', datafield: 'Office', width: 120 }
                ]
            });
        });
```

```css
* {
        font-family: Segoe UI;
        font-size: 10.5pt;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        }
        .jqx-grid {
        border-radius: 0 !important;
        }
        body {
        height:100%;
        }
        header {
        background-color: rgb(93,90,88);
        color: white;
        border: 0;
        margin:0;
        line-height: 25px;
        padding-left: 2px;
        }
        footer {
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
        margin:0;
        border:0;
        line-height:25px;
        background-color: rgb(93,90,88);
        width:100%;
        color: #FFF;
        padding-left: 2px;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
        box-sizing: border-box; 
        }
        #wrapper {
        position:absolute;
        width:100%;
        margin:0;
        }
        #topbar {
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-left: 2px;
        background-color: rgb(216,216,216);
        color: rgb(76,83,92);
        }
        .center {
        margin: auto;
        border: 3px solid #73AD21;
        padding: 10px;
        }
        .input_txt_search {
        background: url(icons/search.png) no-repeat right;
        background-size: 16px;
        border: 1px solid rgb(171,173,179);
        padding: 2px;
        width: 200px;
        background-color: #FFF;
        }
        .input_txt {
        border: 1px solid rgb(171,173,179);
        padding: 2px;
        width: 200px;
        }
        .input_txt:hover, .input_txt_search:hover, .selectbox:hover  {
        border-color: rgb(93,90,88);
        }
        .selectbox {
        width: 206px;
        padding: 2px;
        border: 1px solid rgb(171,173,179);
        background: url(icons/arrow.png) no-repeat right #fff;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        background-position-x: 182px;
        }
        input:-webkit-autofill,
        input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
        input:-webkit-autofill:focus, 
        input:-webkit-autofill:active  {
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
        color: white !important;
        }

        p {
        margin: 0 0 20px;
        line-height: 1.5;
        }
        .main {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
        }
        .content {
        background: #fff;
        border: 1px solid rgb(171,173,179);
        }
        .content>div {
        display: none;
        padding: 20px 25px 5px;
        }
        input[name="tabs"] {
        display: none;
        }
        label {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
        border-top: 1px solid rgb(171,173,179);
        border-left: 1px solid rgb(171,173,179);
        border-right: 1px solid rgb(171,173,179);
        width: 115px;
        padding: 10px;
        }
        label:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        background: rgb(196,196,196);
        }
        input[name="tabs"]:checked+label {
        background: #fff;
        color: #000;
        border-top: 1px solid rgb(171,173,179);
        border-left: 1px solid rgb(171,173,179);
        border-right: 1px solid rgb(171,173,179);
        border-bottom: 0px;
        position: relative;
        font-weight: bold;
        }
        input[name="tabs"]:checked+label::before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 1px;
        background: #fff;
        bottom: -1px;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin: auto;
        }
        #tab1:checked~.content #content1,
        #tab2:checked~.content #content2,
        #tab3:checked~.content #content3,
        #tab4:checked~.content #content4 {
        display: block;
        }
        
#grid {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqwidgets/14.0.0/jqwidgets/jqx-all.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqwidgets/14.0.0/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqwidgets/14.0.0/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.energyblue.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="topbar">
            <form name="GO" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="Search" class="input_txt_search" />
                <input type = "submit" name="GO" value="GO"/>
                <input type = "submit" name="Test" value="Test" onclick="test()"/>
            </form>
        </div><!-- End of DIV Wrapper -->

        <div class="center">

            <div id="content">
                <div class="main">
                    <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked><label for="tab1">Office Info</label>
                    <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs"><label for="tab2">Employee Info</label>
                    <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs"><label for="tab3">Service Requests</label>
                    <input id="tab4" type="radio" name="tabs"><label for="tab4">Tokyo</label>
                    <div class="content">
                        <div id="content1">
                            <form method="post">
                                <table style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 5px;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>FirstName:</td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="FirstName" class="input_txt"  /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>LastName:</td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="LastName" class="input_txt" /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Floor:</td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="Floor" class="input_txt"/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Office:</td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="Office" class="input_txt"/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Options:</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <select class="selectbox">
                                                <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                                                <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type = "submit" name="Submit" value = "Submit"/></td>
                                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </form>
                            <%
                                If Request.Form("Submit") <> "" then                 
                                
                                add_new
                                
                                End If
                                %>
                        </div>
                        <div id="content2">
                            <p>
                                London is the capital city of England and the United Kingdom. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants. Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia,
                                its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                London's ancient core, the City of London, largely retains its 1.12-square-mile (2.9 km2) mediaeval boundaries and in 2011 had a resident population of 7,375, making it the smallest city in England. Since at least the 19th century, the term London has
                                also referred to the metropolis developed around this core.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="content3">
                            <p>
                                Mumbai is the capital city of the Indian state of Maharashtra. It is the most populous city in India, most populous metropolitan area in India, and the eighth most populous city in the world, with an estimated city population of 18.4 million and metropolitan
                                area population of 20.7 million as of 2011. Along with the urban areas, including the cities of Navi Mumbai, Thane, Bhiwandi, Kalyan, it is one of the most populous urban regions in the world.
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                Mumbai lies on the west coast of India and has a deep natural harbour. In 2009, Mumbai was named an alpha world city. It is also the wealthiest city in India, and has the highest GDP of any city in South, West or Central Asia.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="content4">
                            <p>
                                Tokyo, officially Tokyo Metropolis, is one of the 47 prefectures of Japan. Tokyo is the capital of Japan, the center of the Greater Tokyo Area, and the most populous metropolitan area in the world. It is the seat of the Japanese government and the Imperial
                                Palace, and the home of the Japanese Imperial Family.
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                Tokyo is in the Kantō region on the southeastern side of the main island Honshu and includes the Izu Islands and Ogasawara Islands. Tokyo Metropolis was formed in 1943 from the merger of the former Tokyo Prefecture and the city of Tokyo.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="grid"></div>

        </div><!-- END OF DIV #CONTENT-->

    </div><!-- END OF DIV #CENTER -->

    </div><!-- END OF DIV #WRAPPER -->
```